# SAS infile messy format of variable lengths

Tags: sas

I have a messy file, where some of the columns are tab delimitated and some are comma.

My problem with the data set is reading the files with variable lengths

```
12        Stephen Cole, 33, Columbia, MO
5          Dave Anderson, 25*, Concord, OH
```

The first column is a ID (tab) the the name (comma) age (comma), active (presence of an asterisk after age), home (tab)

The * after the age indicates if they are inactive.

All the names start at column @19, but everything after that is variable lengths and column starts.

I want to read into a format where I finally get.

```
ID   Name           Age  Active     Home
12   Stephen Cole   33   Active     Columbia, MO
5    Dave Anderson  25   Inactive   Concord, OH
```

Thus far I have:

```
data marathon;
   infile 'c:/file.txt' dlm=',' pad firstobs=12;
   input @3 ID 3. @19 Name $CHAR13.;
```

Then I get stuck on how to read the rest. I am mostly thrown with how to read the asterisk next to the age as its own column. If I had that understood, I think I can handle the rest.

Comment: Fixed up your data.  If those `<br>` fields are supposed to be there, put them back - I assume you were using them for layout purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of issues.  First, you need to use delimited input, specifically you need to combine comma and tab into one set of delimiters - one way is shown below.  Second, you have two fields that are nontrivial; the one with the asterisk needs to be parsed afterwards (I use `compress` to keep specifically digits in the first line, and to keep specifically asterisks in the second line).  You also need to read city/state in separate fields and combine them together (I use `catx`).

```
data want;
infile "c:\temp\test.dat" dlm='092C'x;
input
id
name :$50.
age_active $
home_city :$25.
home_st $
;
age=input(compress(age_active,,'kd'),best.);
active = ifc(compress(age_active,'*','k')='*','Active','Inactive');
home = catx(', ',home_city,home_st);
run;
```

Watch your lengths, I suggest reasonable ones given my past experience but you could see longer names or cities easily.

Comment: @user667489 It is needed for that style of input to use an informat.